map <int, int> c++; какое изначальное значение имеют значения map в int
я знаю что по умолчанию в map <int, int> в значении будет лежать 0, и следовательно map[1]++ то значение будет равно 1. Возможно ли это изменить и положить предположим в начальное значение не 0, а -1?

Переписать map, а заодно и стандарт... Или сделать свой map, унаследованный от стандартного.

Или сделать свою структуру, содержащую int, с конструктором, устанавливающим int в -1. Затем использовать эту структуру в map.

Начальное значение можно задавать произвольно при добавлении нового элемента. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Создавать новую вариацию map или новый тип для значений - это слишком.
В С++ 17 map::try_emplace, а в С++ 11 map::emplace вставляют новый элемент, только если такого ключа в карте не было. Иначе возвращается старый ключ. Код не самый красивый, но эффективный и не очень длинный:
// i - ключ, который обновляется
map.try_emplace(i, -1).first->second++;
// map.emplace(i, -1).first->second++;


В этом случае неважно, но обычно лучше писать try_emplace, чтобы не конструировать значение если оно уже есть в мапе.

@HolyBlackCat, поправил ответ. Спасибо!
